# PHP form mail error

Tags: php

I'm having issue with the sign up button not sending through.

Here's the code from the main page (where the sign up button is):

```
<div class="signup">
                                <form action="sendmail.php" method="post" name="frm-signup" id="frm-signup">
                                    <div id="item-form">
                                    <input class="email"  type="text"  value="Your e-mail address" onclick="value=''" size="20px" name="email" id="jf_email"/>
                                    <input class="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="Sign up" size="95px" id="jf_submit"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="position: relative;">
                                    <div id="jf_error_email" style="display:none;">
                                    <p class="hs_infor">
                                        This isn't a valid email address
                                    </p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <p style="display: none;" id="thank_you">Thank you. We'll update you as soon as possible.</p>
                          </div>
```

Basically what's meant to happen is when you click on the sign up button after entering a valid format of an email address, a message appears below is (thank you. we'll update you etc). At the moment the button just don't work at all. It's not sending emails back to their email not showing up the thank you message.

Here's the php code for the sendmail.php:

```
<?php

$from = "ask@michaelfrieda2014.com";
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']) && $_REQUEST['email'] != '')
{
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    sendMailSingup($from, $email);
    sendMailSingup($from, "ask@michaelfrieda2014.com");
}

function sendMailSingup($from, $to)
{
    include_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail             = new PHPMailer();

    $body             = "Thank you. We'll update you as soon as possible.";    
    $mail->IsSendmail(); // telling the class to use SendMail transport    
    $mail->From       = "$from";
    $mail->FromName   = "Frieda and Michael";
    $mail->Subject    = "Thank you!";    
    $mail->AltBody    = "Thank you!"; // optional, comment out and test    
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);    
    $mail->AddAddress("$to", "");
    //$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");             // attachment
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      #echo "Message sent!";
      echo 1;
    }
}
```

At the moment when you enter in email address, they return as error:

Mailer Error: Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmailMailer Error: Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail

Thanks!

Comment: You are not allowed to run `/usr/sbin/sendmail`. If you need `IsSendmail()` rather then `IsMail()`, examine where the binary is you're allowed to use. If neither work and you can't find the binary, talk to the sysadmin of your box.

Comment: Have you got sendmail installed and configured?

Comment: Sometimes $mail->IsSendmail(); can cause this error. Try commenting it out and see if anything happens.

Comment: Is there any way to make this much simpler? I'm not sure about where to install sendmail..

Comment: I tried commenting out the $mail->IsSendmail(); line and the page basically goes to sendmail.php with a message of "11". Email sends twice. Assuming something to do with the echo.

Comment: It's actually sending a lot of emails, not just one email but more than 10 emails at once. Any idea why it's doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input class="submit" type="button" name="submit"
```

should be :

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit"
```